# How can I center a text in grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

A specific text can't be put in the center in CSS grid.

I have a grid CSS but the text "Post Manager" seems to not go to center. I have made grid items into flex container but only this text seem to not follow the rule. Any thought is appreciated. Thank you.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.gn {
  background-color: #7fd2f0;
  grid-row: 1 / 16;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.ab {
  background-color: #85fedd;
  grid-column: 2/16;
}

.pm {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  grid-row: 2/16;
  grid-column: 2/5;
  text-align: center;
}

.wp {
  background-color: #c6c6c6;
  grid-column: 6/16;
  grid-row: 2/16;
}

.center-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center-text gn">Global Navigation</div>
  <div class="center-text ab">Application Bar</div>
  <div class="center-text pm">Post Manager</div>
  <div class="center-text wp">Writing Space</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `grid-column: 2/5` --> I guess you meant `grid-column: 2/6`

Comment: `.pm { grid-column: 2/6 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
.pm {
    grid-column: 2/6;
}
```